# As projects increase, the number of connections increases

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm using a **Eclipse**, **Tomcat8.5** and connection pool.
Running Tomcat Server will cause problems.
That means there's more connections will increase.

ex)
1. no project / tomcat server : run
 result -> 10 connection Create.

2. one project / tomcat server : run
   result -> 20 connection Create.

...  Number of projects * 10 + 10(tomcat server) = result connection
          ( 8           * 10 + 10                =  90  )

but, project is an empty project.
There's no code, it's just mounted on the server.

connection code is as follows:

```
<Resource 
name="jdbc/myoracle" 
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
url="------" 
username="----" 
password="------" 
initialSize="10" 
maxTotal="10" 
maxIdle="10" 
minIdle="10" 
maxWaitMillis="5000" />
```

That's a `context.xml` Code.

No other code has been written from any file.

What the hell is wrong?

Comment: initialSize="10".  If the project is empty, what is "run result" ?

Comment: When is initialSize null?  initialSize=""  this? If you get it right, the result is an error. I didn't understand the question.
result : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: what is a numeric empty value? probably 0

Comment: sorry, initialSize="0" and the results of one project are as follows: Connection not created. (Zero) And if it's initialSize="2", the result is four connections.                    Number of projects * initialSize + initialSize = result connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using Tomcat's shared connection pool.

Move the `<Resource>` to the `<GlobalNamingResources>` section of `server.xml`, then use a `<ResourceLink name="jdbc/myoracle" global="jdbc/myoracle" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>` instead.

Now, all of your webapps will share those 10 connections.

You might want to reduce `initialSize` and `minIdle`, e.g. to 1, and if needed raise `maxTotal` to have enough for all the webapps, if you do stuff in them all at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the practical offer. A better code has been created.

Comment: @바보린 I'd like to add, that everything in the `context.xml` is created per-application. So each app gets it's own&independent instance of listeners, valves, resources, etc if defined in the context.xml